# remove scrolling from fixed position element

Tags: css

code sandbox:- https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-wilson-mx6e2m?file=/index.html
how can I remove the scroll bar from this?

Comment: By setting `overflow: hidden;`.

Comment: it is not working(i am putting it in fixed division)

Comment: Instead of posting code, error messages, data, or other text as images or links, please [edit] your post to copy/paste or type the actual text directly into the post (for code, use a [code block](/editing-help#code)). [Text in images cannot be copied to reproduce the issue, and error messages in images cannot be searched](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/208273). Links may become invalid if the linked site changes.  If your code is too long to fit in the post, we have tips on [how to create a minimal, reproducible example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

I checked your code, the fixed position element itself doesn't have scroll, what has scroll is `<body>`, so if understand your question correctly, you probably wanna add `overflow: hidden;` to your `<body>`:

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```